# Why is it not the case that that $\Pr(X > Y)$ is the integral of the CDFS?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$, where $X \sim \text{Laplace}(\mu_x, b)$ and $Y\sim \text{Laplace}(\mu_y, b)$. $\mu_x \leq \mu_y$.

I am trying to find the $\Pr(X > Y)$. To do this, I am using the following strategy.

1. Let $F_x(z)$ be the CDF for $X$ and let $F_y(z)$ be the CDF for $Y$.
2. Compute $P(X > Y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(1 - F_x(z))F_Y(z)dz$

The Laplace CDF is piecewise depending on whether $z < \mu$ or $z \geq \mu$. So I break the integral into three sections

3. Compute $\int_{-\infty}^{\mu_x}(1 - F_x(z))F_y(z)dz + \int_{\mu_x}^{\mu_y}(1 - F_x(z))F_y(z)dz + \int_{\mu_y}^{\infty}(1 - F_x(z))F_y(z)dz$
4. This becomes $\int_{-\infty}^{\mu_x}(1 - \frac{1}{2}\exp(\frac{z - \mu_x}{b}))\frac{1}{2}\exp(\frac{z - \mu_y}{b})dz + \int_{\mu_x}^{\mu_y}\frac{1}{2}\exp(-\frac{z - \mu_x}{b})\frac{1}{2}\exp(\frac{z - \mu_y}{b})dz + \int_{\mu_y}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}\exp(-\frac{z - \mu_x}{b})(1 - \frac{1}{2}\exp(-\frac{z - \mu_y}{b}))dz$

Solving this reduces to

$\frac{3}{4}b\exp(\frac{\mu_x - \mu_y}{b}) + \frac{1}{4}(\mu_y - \mu_x)\exp(\frac{\mu_x - \mu_y}{b})$

But this cannot be the right answer because we should expect that two Laplacian RVs with equal means (i.e. $\mu_x = \mu_y$), we should expect that $\Pr(X > y) = \frac{1}{2}$.

My question is whether or not the initial problem setup (i.e. step 2) is valid? And if not, why not?

Comment: But isn't $P(X>Y)=\int(1-F_x(z))f_y(z)dz$ where $f_y(z)$ is the PDF of $Y$ (not the CDF)?

Comment: @drhab Ah ok - so that's where my error is. But I guess I'm also a little confused by why $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(1 - F_x(z))F_y(z)dz$ is wrong, because it seems like it's measuring the events where $X > z$ and $Y \leq z$?

Comment: I posted an answer to make things more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general if $X,Y$ are random variables defined on the same space:$$P(X>Y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}[x>y]dF_{X,Y}(x,y)$$where $[x>y]$ must be interpreted as a function that takes value $1$ if $x>y$ and takes value $0$ otherwise.

If moreover $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $dF_{X,Y}(x,y)$ can be replaced by $dF_X(x)dF_Y(y)$ resulting in:$$P(X>Y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}[x>y]dF_X(x)dF_Y(y)$$

Now note that:$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}[x>y]dF_X(x)=\int_{(y,\infty)}dF_X(x)=1-F_X(y)$$so that we can write:$$P(X>Y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}1-F_X(y)dF_Y(y)$$If moreover random variable $Y$ has a density $f_Y(y)$ then $dF_Y(y)$ can be replaced by $f_Y(y)dy$ resulting in:$$P(X>Y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(1-F_X(y))f_Y(y)dy$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are independent (since in the problem we don't have any information about the joint distribution), using law of total probability
$$
P(X>Y) = \int P(X>Y\mid Y=y)f_{Y}(y)\, dy= \int P(X>y)f_{Y}(y)\, dy
$$
by independence.